# Back propagation and Structure of a Neural Network in scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn Neural Networks using [scikit-neuralnetwork](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html) framework and I know basics about Neural Networks and now trying to implement it with scikit-learn. but I am confused on 2 points.

1- what is the structure of this NN given below? Somehow, in some examples felt to me, some people don't put input layer as a layer. Otherwise, I am thinking this as a 2 layer NN has input layer with 100 nodes and 1 node at the ouput layer.

```
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

nn = Classifier(
   layers=[
    Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
    Layer("Softmax")],
learning_rate=0.001,
n_iter=25)

nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

2- Does scikit-neuralnetwork do back propagation within the code that I put above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
From what I understand, scikit-neuralnetwork tries to automatically determine the correct input and output sizes by the X and y data you give it when  calling `nn.fit`. Therefore structure should be:

1. Input layer with shape determined by X_train
2. Dense layer with 100 units and maxout activation with 2 linear pieces
3. Softmax classification layer with as many units as needed for y_train

Seems to use input shape from data here:
https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/b7fd0c089bd7c721c4d9cf9ca71eed74c6bafc5e/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py#L183

And output shape from data here:
https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/b7fd0c089bd7c721c4d9cf9ca71eed74c6bafc5e/sknn/mlp.py#L62

**However, note that maxout seems no longer supported**: https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/142

2) Yes it uses backpropagation by calling appropriate lasagne/theano functions to create/compile the backpropagation training function:
https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/b7fd0c089bd7c721c4d9cf9ca71eed74c6bafc5e/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py#L50-L103

(Actual training seems to happen here: https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/blob/b7fd0c089bd7c721c4d9cf9ca71eed74c6bafc5e/sknn/backend/lasagne/mlp.py#L316-L335)

Comment: I confused myself with overthinking. I supposed that those layers are input and output layer but in fact, I saw now that is more clear, I don't need to write input layer and I just need to write the output layer and it's function. Size is already taken by the code itself  `self.layers[-1].units = y.shape[1]`  Thank you so much for all those nice well supported explanations! @robintibor